# Is XML necessary for developing android apps?

Tags: android, xml

I know how to code in `Java` but I heard that `XML` is also needed for developing  android apps. My problem is that I don't know `XML` at all. So is `XML` necessary for developing android apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Certain files, such as `AndroidManifest.xml`, must exist and must be in XML.